# split string of chain functions with reg-exp

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I looked around on StackOverflow but could not find the answer!

Anyway, I was wondering how do I get following in JavaScript with regexp.

I have a string

```
bla().func1($(ele).attr("data")).func2.func3("test")... ;
```

and I want extract func1, func2, func3... from the given string, anybody have an example of how to do that?

Bear in mind, that the function names changes, so they are not func1, func2 ... they can be load, past, moon ... whatever

Comment: You want `func1` and `func2` but not `attr`? That'll be tricky. Do you also need to handle `blah()["func1"](...)` cases?

Comment: Hi T.J. Crowder ... not int. in blah() just the base functions related to blah, such as func1, func2 ... cheers c_bb

Comment: what regex have you tried? what is that you don't understand?

Comment: hi gp ... tried a few different regexp, but regexp is not my strong side, and i can't seem to get the right formula ... cheers c_bb

Comment: Actually, why `func2` because that's not a function call but property access.

Comment: Run it through Esprima and extract the function names from the AST. Trying to parse JS with regexp is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeatedly strip out innermost parenthesized expressions:

```js
var str = 'bla().func1($(ele).attr("data")).func2.func3("test")... ';
var expression = /\([^(]*?\)/g;
 
while (expression.test(str)) { str = str.replace(expression, ''); }

document.write(str.split('.').slice(1).join(' '));
```

However, you shouldn't do this (why do you want to?). JS should be parsed by, well, JS parsers. For instance, the above will fail miserably if there's a string literal containing a parenthesis. You should parse this using Esprima and analyze the resulting parse tree.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var str = 'bla().func1($(ele).attr("data")).func2("test")';
alert(str.split(/(?:\.)\w+\d+(?=\()/g));
```

There's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cv6avhfb/3/

This code would split the string in parts while using as separators substrings like '.func1(', '.func2(', '.abc3(' and other. If the function names have different structure you just have to change the `\w+\d+` part of the regex.

Here's the result of this code:

```
bla(),($(ele).attr("data")),("test")
```

And if you like to know more about regex in javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Hi Dr. Nefario ... the functions name is not nessecary func(somthing) ... the can be load, cast ans so forth, and changes all the time ... so it could be blah().test().moon("whatever") ... cheers c_bb

Comment: Hi Dr. Nefario ... when i do var str = 'bla().test($(ele).attr("data")).load("test")';
alert(str.split(/(?:\.)\w+(?=\()/g)); i get bla(),($(ele),("data")),("test") and unfortunately that is not a useful output .. sorry .. thank you anyways for looking into it ... cheers c_bb

Comment: What is the result you are searching for?